# react-native-fbsdk failing Xcode build

Tags: react-native, facebook-ios-sdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm aware of related questions, but they refer to **Pod** files which are unsupported now, so decided to bring it up again.

This is my call stack on the error:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/Me/Documents/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at /Users/Me/Documents/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKHashtag", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libRCTFBSDK.a(RCTConvert+FBSDKSharingContent.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My `Info.plist` looks something like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb****</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>********</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>My App</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

1. FBSDK resides in `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` and is added to
   `Framework Search Paths` in the `Build Settings` tab (set to
   `recursive`).
2. `Bolts, FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit` all exist in the
       `Framework` group of the Xcode project after dragging them from `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`.
3. `libRCTFBSDK.a` exists in `Link Binaries With Libraries` in the
       `Build Phases` tab.

We've managed to get it working several times, but now it has stopped working when building.

We also don't include any Pods related to Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging around,
turns out that the order in which `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` is added to `Framework Search Paths` in the *Build Settings* tab is important.

I brought it to the top and it builds.
Seems to have no side effects on Login, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, only opens the file xcworkspace from xcode .
This works